# How can I always show the UIScrollBar indicator?

Tags: swift

When a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` is visible on screen, I want to show the `UIScrollView` scrollbar indicator.

Is there a way to show the indicator?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the scrollbar momentarily with `.flashScrollIndicators` when the view controller has been added to the view hierarchy and is potentially visible to the user.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
 }
```